# Gridview in fragment

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to use a `GridView` in a layout but my code is saying I can't make a static reference to a non-static method. I thought using a `GridView` in a `Fragment` would be the same as an `Activity`

This is my code:

```
public static class MiscFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public MiscFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc_fragment,
                container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I will then set `gridview` to an `Adapter`. The problem is currently caused by `findViewById(R.id.gridview);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview)`.